# How to make a Diagram like these for research papers?

Tags: thesis, writing

im writing a research paper and as part of it I am discussing methods of calibrating a 3D camera. I found this image from another paper i was reading and was wanting to replicate it for my own paper but im not sure how they did it. If anyone has any ideas for making something like this then id really appreciate if you could let me know.

[image: Camera project image.]